# How to check if all specific object has a same value in array?

Tags: javascript

I have an example JS Object like this:

```
var a = [
  {
    "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision4",
  },
  {
    "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision4",
  },
  {
    "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision4",
  },
]

var b = [
  {
    "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision4",
  },
  {
    "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision3",
  },
  {
    "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision4",
  },
]
```

I've spent a couple hours to find any possible duplicated question, but not find it yet,

How to handle if `var a` is true and `return`ing `TKRRevision4`?

Comment: You want to check all a value exist in b or something else?

Comment: Please explain your requirements as this is not clear what you intend to achieve. ALso show us what you tried so far

Comment: `a`, as an Array of Objects will always be `true`  when converted to a Boolean.

Comment: @NishantDixit I just use different type of object value in array to telling if `a` is true and `b` is false, because `b` has `TKRRevision3`

Comment: @BogdanM.  I just tried and stuck to handle the value using [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and which is the better way, because I'm handling those JSON in `react native`

Comment: @flix then please post the code you tried to solve your problem and how it didn't work the way it should as an edit to your question!

Comment: @Luca all I've did is just doing `var result =this.state.datamentah.some((item)=>{/*stuck to handle the value */})` because im not familiar with JS, and `this.state.datamentah` is like `var a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var a = [{
        "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision4",
    },
    {
        "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision4",
    },
    {
        "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision4",
    },
]

var b = [{
        "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision4",
    },
    {
        "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision3",
    },
    {
        "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision4",
    },
]

function checkValue(response) {
    var c = a.every(val => val.Procedure_Code == response.key)
    var d = b.every(val => val.Procedure_Code == response.key)
    return {
        a: c,
        b: d
    };
}
var apiResponse = {
    key: "TKRRevision4"
};
var validation = checkValue(apiResponse);
console.log("a => " + validation.a);
console.log("b => " + validation.b);
```

Comment: can you post the example code without hardcoded the value? because my value is dynamically

Comment: `dynamically `? from where dynamic value is coming ?

Comment: @flix, i posted an answer using a generic method which check for all the object properties(in case you have more than one property)

Comment: I got the value from API and it can change dynamically value but with static `key`

Comment: thanks sir, it makes me clearly to handle the response,

Answer (score 1):

You can use `every` method by passing a *callback* function as argument which is applied for every item from your given array.

```js
var a = [ { "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision4", }, { "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision4", }, { "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision4", }, ]
var b = [ { "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision4", }, { "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision3", }, { "Procedure_Code": "TKRRevision4", }, ]


function check(array){
   let first_obj = array[0];
   return array.every( elem => Object
                       .keys(elem)
                       .every(key => elem[key] == first_obj[key]));
}


let result_a = check(a);
let result_b = check(b);

console.log(result_a);
console.log(result_b);
```